# .NET allow an "extra access" to a folder

Tags: .net-core, authorization

(.NET Core 3.1 application)

Now, I may have cornered myself with this ... ,

**Folder Structure**

[image]

To access `Account` folders the user needs to be in the role `administrator`

```
options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Administration", "/Account", "RequireAdministrator");
```

```
options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministrator", policy => policy
    .RequireRole("Administrator")
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser());
```

**What I want**

I created a new role: `DataConsulter` which I want to give access to `Account/Records`, but I don't want it to be in `administrator` role. Also this new role shouldn't be needed for `administrator` users to access the `Account/Records` folder. Can I achieve this without changing the folders structure? Should I?

I guess I want something like this (after removing the previous access as suggested by @jb11):

```
options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministrator", policy => policy
    .RequireRole("Administrator" || "DataConsulter")
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser());
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `AuthorizeAreaFolder`, an `AuthorizeAttribute` is [added](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages/DependencyInjection/PageConventionCollectionExtensions.cs,6966ddd2308d256a,references) to the `PageApplicationModel`'s `EndpointMetadata`.

Therefore, to override the authorisation for a specific folder this attribute needs to be removed. This can be achieved by calling `AddFolderApplicationModelConvention`, identifying the attribute and removing it.

```
options.Conventions.AddFolderApplicationModelConvention("/Account/Records", action =>
                        {
                        var authorizeAttribute = action.EndpointMetadata.FirstOrDefault(r => r is AuthorizeAttribute {Policy: "RequireAdministrator"});
                        if (authorizeAttribute != null)
                        {
                            action.EndpointMetadata.Remove(authorizeAttribute);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: While I feel like I need this somewhere in the path to the answer, it doesn't really answer it. I have updated my question a bit, if you could take a look. Also what does x stand for in `action.EndpointMetadata.Remove(x);` (I guess `authorizeAttribute `)?